# What is this extra space above my appbar?

Tags: flutter

[image]

This is the default flutter application template with only some extra styling for the title.

EDIT:
Here is a better image without transparency. I am referring to the space above the Appbar
[image]

Comment: are you referring to the toolbar?

Comment: I edited my post

Comment: Could we see your code? the class where you defined AppBar

Answer (score 1):

```
 MaterialApp(
        home: HomePage());
  }
```

Use MaterialApp Not Scaffold();

Comment: And just create the title as a separate Text widget?

Comment: Alright ill do that, but ill leave this post open as I still am curious what that extra space is

Comment: Extra Space is the Padding , By Default Scaffold Padding

Comment: You probably have a Scaffold inside a Scaffold which can cause this

Answer (score 0):

This extra space is toolbar height that related to your virtual device model. please change your device and then see what happened. I guess the problem is virtual device screen.
Or you can use SafeArea Widget to solve your problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).